# Search for "google+" on Twitter without regular "google" in results

Tags: twitter, search, google-plus, twitter-api

How do you search for "google+" on Twitter without results also showing the form without the plus sign (`+`)?

I want to search for the literal **google+** on Twitter. Unfortunately, the plus gets encoded and the Twitter search API does not find any results. Results appear the same as if there was no plus sign.

Comment: What URI are you using? Tested it fine via the API and the search page

Comment: http://twitter.com/?q=google%2B#!/search works

Comment: @phwd: Perhaps, but it doesn't appear to be any different than a simple search for "google".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be your best bet for now within Google Search as Google may have added it as a special reserved word in a similar format to say c++

> site:twitter.com inurl:status google+

The following *seems* to search Google and Google+ but if you look at the results in realtime, there are also results that do not make any sense.

> twitter.com/?q=google%2B#!/search

Comment: Maybe those that don't make sense come from the URL shorteners